# GTest Undefined reference

Tags: c, cmake

Directory Like picture
[image: Directory]

in Root Directory C CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(yx_ip C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)


#########
# GTest #
#########
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(libs/gtest-1.7.0)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

 ###########
 # Project #
 ###########
add_executable(yx_ip main.c)
add_subdirectory(libs/arp)
add_subdirectory(libs/base)
add_subdirectory(unit_test)
target_link_libraries(yx_ip BASE ARP)
```

in the `unit_test` Directory is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

set(TEST_PROJECT_NAME UnitsTests)
file(GLOB LIBRARY_TESTS_SOURCE *.cpp)

project(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME})



 enable_testing()

if (NOT (TARGET gtest AND TARGET gtest_main))
   message(FATAL_ERROR "gtest and gtest_main targets NOT found")
endif()

add_executable(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBRARY_TESTS_SOURCE})

#target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME} BASE)
target_link_libraries(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME} BASE gtest gtest_main)

add_test(${TEST_PROJECT_NAME}, ${TEST_PROJECT_NAME})
```

but if a run make makefile then

```
unit_test/utils_test.cpp:6: undefined reference to `pasrse_ip_address(char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but if just build `main.c`, result is ok.

Comment: code in here:   https://github.com/yannxia/yx-tcp-ip

Comment: Is `parse_ip_address` a function in your project?

Comment: @StephenNewell yes，it's impl in utils.c, define in uitls.h

Comment: Are you linking whatever library provides `parse_ip_address` into your target?  If it's not in a library, then are you adding the relevant source file to your target?

Comment: @StephenNewell parse_ip_address in fact is provide by base.a static lib，if i comment it , everthing is ok, so, i think is the library not work. but  if build a main, this libaray is work .

Comment: You need to link `parse_ip_address` into your test in some way, either directly (by adding it as one of the test sources) or telling cmake to link against some library.

Comment: Is your error actually complaining about "*pasrse*_ip_address", because if so it looks like you have a typo in your function call...

Comment: @SeanBurton i fix it, because is c and c++ compile error, set extern "C" make it ok